# Entity Framework ensure OnModelCreating is called

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using a dependency injection container for my application, including my EF database contexts.  I recently found out that OnModelCreating is not being called because I'm never doing the typical 
`using(var contexnt = new MyContext)...` rigmarole.  The constructor for my context looks like:

```
public UserAccessContext(string connectionString):base(connectionString)
        {
            this.connectionString = connectionString;
            Database.SetInitializer<UserAccessContext>(null);
        }
```

My issue is that in my OnModelCreating I'm mapping a table which isn't reasonably named (outside of my control) to a domain object.  EF is trying to use convention to figure out the table name and guessing wrong.  How can I keep using DI for injecting the dependency of my context, but also ensure that the configuration code is will be called?

This application is a .NET core application, using the built in DI container for .NET core web api:

```
services.AddScoped<IUserAccessContext>(_ => new UserAccessContext(userAccessConnectinString));
```

OnModelCreating configuration

```
var remediationAuditLogConfig = dbModelBuilder.Entity<RemediationAuditLog>()
                .ToTable("dbo.PoorlyNamedTable");
            remediationAuditLogConfig.HasKey(x => x.Id);
```

Comment: Could you add the code where the context is registered with whichever DI framework you're using. Sounds like you're using the DB first style, could you confirm? How are you mapping the not reasonably named table?

Comment: @phuzi updated.  Yes, this is a database first